# How to manage predefined groups in couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I am new to couchdb so bear with me if this is really easy.

I am trying to prototype a system where there is group of user who can share everything within a database to each other.  For example, think of a message board system that once a user is allow into a particular board, they can view/update/delete anything in that message board.  Also, a user can join multiple boards.

From what I read so far, the way I am thinking to achieve this is to have multiple database within the couchdb server.  Each database represents a board and since board doesn't need to talk to each other, this give a nice separation between boards.

My question is about user authorization.  I know that I can create user in couchdb and assign them ACL within one "database", but is there a way in couchdb that it controls user access in a "database" level?  ie. which database can a user read/write/update?

the only way I see now is to have another table in a "application" database can control user access, basically a mapping from user to database.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to contradict yourself.  You say that you know you can assign a user an ACL within one database, and then you ask if there's a way to control user access in a database.

All authorization is at a database level.  Read the [Authorization section of the Security docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview#Authorization).